# Add a form to admin side

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I need to create a form to admin-side with two fields

1. Number of code: integer
2. Value of code: float

How can I do that. This form is not related to any model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your modelless form as explained in @levi's answer.
Then, you can place it in the admin site in a number of different ways, depending your needs:

- Make instances of the form available to all templates via a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext), and [override the admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) to have it rendered wherever you want. You can create a view for only processing the form.
- Create a view for both rendering and processing the form in a unique place, and hook it up to the admin [as explained in the old Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter17/#cn62), you'll need to make sure the template for that view extends one of the admin's templates (`admin/change_form.html` may be a good choice).

Answer (score 0):

```
from django import forms

class Your_Form(forms.Form):
    number_code = forms.IntegerField()
    value_code  = forms.FloatField()
```

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question. I meant I need to add to admin-site